# How can I test google.protobuf.Timestamp in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

Using a proto file from an API created in Scala. My code is in JS, trying to test my code and getting the following error:

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: invalid return value: post[0].lastPublishedDate: Date expected
```

Tried and didn't work:

1. `lastPublishedDate: {seconds: <date>, nano: <date>}`, with date being a date's toISOString() like mentioned in the docs (https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto#L115)
2. `lastPublishedDate: new Date().toISOString()`
3. Just putting `2019-02-18T14:18:45.346Z` (that's what the API seems to return when I call it) as the date.

Nothing seems to work for me.

The only other reference to this I could find online is this:
https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js/issues/437
and it also seems unsolved.

Has anyone managed to work with google.protobuf.Timestamp in JS?

Answer (score 15):

you can use this function to generate Date based on this `google/protobuf/timestamp.proto`

```
const getDate = ()=>{
    if (window.proto) {
        const proto = window.proto;
        const timeMS = Date.now();
        const timestamp = new proto.google.protobuf.Timestamp()
        timestamp.setSeconds(timeMS / 1000);
        timestamp.setNanos((timeMS % 1000) * 1e6);
        return timestamp;
    }
}
```

OR you can use this one as well:

```
const date = new proto.google.protobuf.Timestamp()
date.fromDate(new Date())
```

and for getting JS date you can use `toDate()` method from `proto.google.protobuf.Timestamp`

hope it helps you.

Comment: `setSeconds` and `setNanos` didn't work for me for some reason, but the `fromDate` did. Thanks!

Comment: Same with me and this answer saved my day. Huge thank you!

Comment: Thank you - wow this is janky syntax.  WTF google!??!

Answer (score 2):

So apparently it was a regular JS date (`new Date()`), like could be figured out from the error message...