# How to convert js date to protobuff Timestamp

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers

```
let today = new Date();
```

how we can convert regular js date to protobuf Timestamp?

Comment: already answered here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849843/how-can-i-test-google-protobuf-timestamp-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thats the regular "toISOString" method

```
const today = new Date();
const newToday= today.toISOString();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).